# vba -> sharepoint -> file_manipulation | check-in / check-out programmatically

Tags: vba, sharepoint, checkin

I want to overwrite a file in sharepoint using vba.  I cannot do this when a file is checked-out.  How do I forcibly check-in a file on sharepoint that is checked-out?

Answer (score 0):

-create a linked table to check if the file is checked out
-if it is, use kill to remove the file
-docmd.outputo yourfile